# Persisting OneToMany relationship Using JPA without Join table

Tags: database, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data

I have the following tableS:

```
`notification_job_execution`
(`jobId`,
`createdDate`,
`messageBody`)

`notification_task_execution`
(`taskId`,
`jobId`,
`status`,
`createdDate`)
```

Havin oneToMany relationshop (notification_job_execution ,notification_task_execution)
                                                      (1..n)

I have the following entities

```
  @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
    private String jobId;
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date createdDate;
    private String messageBody;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "notificationJobEntity", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<NotificationTaskEntity> notificationTaskEntities = new HashSet<NotificationTaskEntity>(
            0);
```

and:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "notification_task_execution")
public class NotificationTaskEntity implements Serializable{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long taskId;

    private int jobId;


    private String status;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date createdDate;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private NotificationJobEntity notificationJobEntity;
```

I am using Spring and JPA in order to persist this way:

```
  NotificationJobEntity notificationJobEntity=new NotificationJobEntity();
        notificationJobEntity.setCreatedDate(new Date());
        notificationJobEntity.setMessageBody("hello youu");


          NotificationTaskEntity notificationTaskEntity=new NotificationTaskEntity();
          notificationTaskEntity.setCreatedDate(new Date());
          notificationTaskEntity.setStatus("success");
          notificationTaskEntity.setNotificationJobEntity(notificationJobEntity);

        notificationTaskEntity.setNotificationJobEntity(notificationJobEntity);
        notificationJobEntity.getNotificationTaskEntities().add(notificationTaskEntity);

        notificationDao.save(notificationJobEntity);
```

I cant see in the database the child record persisted ( which is notificationTaskEntity).

How could I persist the parent and under the hood having the notificationTaskEntity to be persisted to the database as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you may just need to add the `@JoinColumn` annotation to indicate which field in the database table represents the ID of the `NotificationTaskEntity`.

```
@ManyToOne(optional = false)
@JoinColumn(name = "jobid")
private NotificationJobEntity notificationJobEntity;
```

Comment: But I should have the field jobId inside NotificationTaskEntity as well(As a field and in the constructor ) ?

Comment: I got exception: Column 'jobId' specified twice

Comment: @rayman Remove `private int jobId`, I don't think you need it

Answer (score 0):

You must specify the `CascadeType` in the `NotificationTaskEntity`

```
@ManyToOne(optional = false,CascadeType.PERSIST)
    private NotificationJobEntity notificationJobEntity;
```